# How to encrypt and securely store and transmit private keys of SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption

I have to generate ssh key pairs for multiple server instances, and keep the private keys in the same/other server for further automation tasks.

What are some ways to protect these keys in case of a hacking attempt?

Does [AWS Key Management Service](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/) can help to secure these key files, one possible solution I am thinking is to

1. Keep the private keys encrypted with AWS KMS and Keep the keep the key in database with the AWS key ID.

And then I will transmit the encrypted private key related to the automation server and then the decryption of Key happens in the automation server which calls aws for decryption and then use the plaintext ssh private key to authenticate with the instance.

Is this a viable approach? I feel like this is just an added layer of security rather than a solid solution. What are some approaches would help here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can encrypt these keys with KMS, when you encrypt the content you will receive both a plain text and encrypted copy of the data encryption key (both are Base64 encoded).

When you store the object in the data store you would need to save it with the encrypted data encryption key. Then when you need to retrieve this key you would decrypt it using the CMK.

Comment: The issue is the instances I manage are not only AWS instances, So ssh is necessary. And the services you have metioned applies only to AWS services. Even though my app runs inside AWS  the servers I manage are probably spread throughout AWS, Digital Ocean etc...

Comment: Using the KMS, I am planning to encrypt my private keys and store them, then using KMS I decrypt when I need the plain text. So per customer there will be a CMK, using that I will encrypt a their private key. I am not planning to decrypt the CMK itself, I know I can't decrypt the CMK itself.

Comment: Ah right, I think there was a misunderstanding on your question. Then yes using KMS is fine with this encrypt others PEMs and then store the encrypted key :)

Comment: I have updated the answer to account for my misunderstanding :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking into [AWS Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/intro.html) for this. Secrets Manager will allow you store the SSH keys in an encrypted form, using the KMS key of your choice, and control access to each SSH key using IAM policies.

Comment: But,isn't this poses the same threat as having access to the server will directly give access to all the possible secrets?. But with KMS, will at least prevent leaking all the keys together since each of them are encrypted with a separate CMK, and to decrypt the keys you will have to use specific CMK, which I will probably salt it with some logic :O, and probably you will have to go through the code to figure this out. What is your opinion?